# Unity 4.6 hide / unhide button using C# script

Tags: button, unity-game-engine, hide

I've been working on a project in Unity 4.6 where it is necessary to hide and unhide buttons using C# script. Does anyone have an example on how to do this?

Comment: Hide in means of disabling? If so, you can use `SetActive(false/true)`.

Comment: It's a virtual keyboard made of several buttons. I'm using FindGameObjectWithTag to find each button and then using Setactive(false) to hide them. It's part of a spelling game where you select a button and if the text of the button is a letter in a word, a UI Text is updated with the letter, then the letter is hidden from the keyboard. The problem is finding them to unhide them when the player selects the next word in the database.

Answer (score 1):

When a gameObject or component is set to inactive using `SetActive(false)` you cannot use any of the "Find" or "GetComponent" type functions. The only way you can reactivate the gameobject or component is to have a reference to it.

In your project could you store the keys in a list or array on startup? you could then iterate through the collection and reactive the disabled keys as needed.

Comment: This. Or just drop them into a public array/list variable via the inspector.

Comment: I thought about doing that. I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Where is SetActive defined? I don't see it anywhere in the new UI.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show/hide a GUI object, and don't want to disable it just

1. Add CanvasGroup to the object
2. Set its alpha to 1 or 0 for show/hide CanvasGroup: `GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 1;`

Answer (score -1):

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Showandhide : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject button;//assign the button object here
    private bool isShowing;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("escape"))
        {
            isShowing = !isShowing;
            button.SetActive(isShowing);
        }
    }
}
```